# Powershell opens new cmd window, when running python script

Tags: python, powershell

Recently i re-installed python. Now when i type ".\script.py" in powershell, it opens new cmd window, but i wanted to launch in the same window. How to change it?
P.S. cmd works fine.

Comment: Either `py -3 .\script.py` or `py -2 .\script.py`, no? They both work for me.

Comment: Unknown option: -2                                                 
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...  
Try `python -h' for more information.      The same for "-3"

Comment: Then try `python .\script.py`. Also, make sure that `.py` is listed among the executable extensions in `$env:PATHEXT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Conda / Anaconda, I did the following command to invoke the correct Python executable for the correct environment I was in (executing this command from an Administrator CMD session):

`ftype Python.File="%CONDA_PREFIX%\python.exe" "%1" %*`

Otherwise it won't recognize the libraries installed for the activated environment.

And also of course:

- Add .PY to the PATHEXT System variables (from the Environment Variables dialog box of System Properties)
- Associate .py with Python.File from an Administrator CMD prompt.
  `assoc .py=Python.File`

Once this was done, both DOS and Powershell command lines worked as expected.